# Ap-hotspot fail

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, hostapd

I've been trying to create an AP wireless network from a usb wifi transmitter.
I have been using ap-hotspot to do so.
It has got no further than this message on debug mode:

```
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
/etc/rc0.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc1.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc6.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc2.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc3.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc4.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc5.d/K85dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
* Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server configuration syntax check
...fail!
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
iptables v1.4.18: Empty interface is likely to be undesired
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

It hangs at this point. Where would I start looking to make it work?

I tried disabling my firewall (Just incase) but nothing I seem to do will make it work.
I am running on Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Thanks for your help.